# ActiveRecord select with OR and exclusive limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the need to query the database and retrieve the last 10 objects that are either active or declined. We use the following:

```
User.where(status: [:active, :declined]).limit(10)
```

Now we need to get the last 10 of each status (total of 20 users)

I've tried the following:

```
User.where(status: :active).limit(10).or(User.where(status: : declined).limit(10))
# SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."status" = $1 OR "users"."status" = $2) LIMIT $3
```

This does the same as the previous query and returns only 10 users, of mixed statuses.

How can I get the last 10 active users and the last 10 declined users with a single query?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that SQL allows doing what you want. First thing I would try would be to use a subquery, something like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :active, -> { where status: :active }
  scope :declined, -> { where status: :declined }
  scope :last_active_or_declined, -> {
    where(id: active.limit(10).pluck(:id))
      .or(where(id: declined.limit(10).pluck(:id))
  }
end
```

Then somewhere else you could just do

```
User.last_active_or_declined()
```

What this does is to perform 2 different subqueries asking separately for each of the group of users and then getting the ones in the propper group ids. I would say you could even forget about the `pluck(:id)` parts since ActiveRecord is smart enough to add the proper `select` clause to your `SQL`, but I'm not 100% sure and I don't have any Rails project at hand where I can try this.

Comment: Yes, you are right: without `pluck` (or with explicit `.select(:id)`) it will construct one fast query. One thing: add `.order(id: :desc)` to both sub-queries to meet "**last** 10 objects" condition from init post.

Comment: This solution does work but will make 3 queries to replace 2. 1º get last active ids, 2º get last declined ids, 3º get users by id. This does work, but I could just as easily call `User.where(status: :active).last(10) + User.where(status: :declined).last(10)` which results in 2 SQL queries. __EDIT__ as exemplified by Steve in the answer below.

Comment: Also, I've just realized, you don't need the `or` call. You could just call `where(id: active.limit(10).pluck(:id) + declined.limit(10).pluck(:id))`. Explanation: `pluck` returns an array, calling `where` with an array for a attribute will make an SQL that already performs an OR query

Comment: Well, the difference is that my solution gives you all the results in an active record collection, which can be chained to other scopes while the other gives you an array if I'm not mistaken. Besides active record will organize everything into a single query with sub queries.

Comment: @NicosKaralis Check my comment and you will get one query with all benefits.

Answer (score 0):

`limit` is not a permitted value for `#or` relationship. If you check the Rails code, the Error raised come from [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L635):

```
def or!(other) # :nodoc:
  incompatible_values = structurally_incompatible_values_for_or(other)

  unless incompatible_values.empty?
    raise ArgumentError, "Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: #{incompatible_values}"
  end
  # more code
end
```

You can check which methods are restricted further down in the code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L1188):

```
STRUCTURAL_OR_METHODS = Relation::VALUE_METHODS - [:extending, :where, :having, :unscope, :references]
def structurally_incompatible_values_for_or(other)
  STRUCTURAL_OR_METHODS.reject do |method|
    get_value(method) == other.get_value(method)
  end
end
```

You can see in the `Relation` class [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L10) that limit is restricted:

```
SINGLE_VALUE_METHODS = [:limit, :offset, :lock, :readonly, :reordering,
                        :reverse_order, :distinct, :create_with, :skip_query_cache,
                        :skip_preloading]
```

So you will have to resort to raw SQL I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with a single query, but you can do it with two queries, get the record ids, and then build a query using those record ids.

It's not ideal but as you're just plucking ids the impact isn't too bad.

```
user_ids = User.where(status: :active).limit(10).pluck(:id) + User.where(status: :declined).limit(10).pluck(id)
users = User.where(id: user_ids)
```

Comment: This should work but it is making 3 queries. A simpler solution would be `User.where(status: :active).last(10) + User.where(status: :declined).last(10)` which I want to avoid because I don't get only 2 scopes and not only 20 users are collected. As such the request is getting really out of hand in production

Comment: I am assuming you want an active record relation, whereas your suggestion will make an array. Whatever works, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `UNION`. Install [active_record_union](https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union) and replace `or` with `union`:

```
User.where(status: :active).limit(10).union(User.where(status: :declined).limit(10))
```